# SSRS exported record count different than SQL Server record count

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Running the same query on SQL server and the SSRS report with the same query results in different record counts.

All, I've got a query as an embedded data set in a report on SSRS2012. When I run the SQL in SQL Server I get x number of records. When I run the report against the same server and export the records to Excel or CSV, the record count is different.

Here's the code:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '11/01/2018'
DECLARE @Enddate DATE = '11/30/2018'

SELECT distinct 
              pat.PatientFirstName, 
              pat.PatientLastName, 
              clm.Patient_UniqueID, 
              prov.ProviderFullName,
              clm.DN_PlaceOfServiceCode,
              clm.Specialty_UniqueID,  
              hp.LineOfBusinessShortName,
              hp.HealthPlanShortName,
              loc.LocationShortName,
              clm.dateofservice,
              clm.DateReceived,
              pat.PatientStreet1,
              pat.PatientStreet2,
              pat.PatientCity,
              pat.PatientState,
              pat.PatientZip,
              pat.PatientPhone

 from ODS_CLM_CLAIM as clm (readuncommitted)
        inner join ODS_PAT_PATIENT as pat (readuncommitted) on 
pat.Patient_UniqueID = clm.Patient_UniqueID and pat.ods_row_current = 1
       inner join ODS_PRV_PROVIDER as prov (readuncommitted) on 
prov.Provider_UniqueID = clm.RenderingProvider_UniqueID and 
prov.ods_row_current = 1
       inner join ODS_LKP_HEALTHPLAN as hp (readuncommitted) on 
clm.HealthPlan_UniqueID = hp.HealthPlan_UniqueID and hp.ods_row_current = 1
       inner join ODS_LKP_LOCATION as loc (readuncommitted) on 
clm.Location_UniqueID = loc.Location_UniqueID and loc.ods_row_current = 1

Where clm.DateReceived between @StartDate and @EndDate
and clm.ods_row_current = 1
and patientstate not in  ('CA','TX')
```

The SQL Server gives me 8070 records While the SSRS report export gives me 8063 records. The only difference is the Embedded SQL is missing the declare statements as the variables are parameters in the report. 
Is there a bug in SSRS that would cause this discrepancy?

Comment: No, there will be a subtlety with something like the parameter datatypes... for example SSRS will most likely be using a datetime not a date. If you can identify one of the records which appears in SSMS and not in SSRS then you'll get a clue (but I'm guessing thats tricky).

Comment: Load your 8063 records into a #temp table and write an exclude query by adding "exclude select * from #temp" to the end of the query above. This will give you the seven missing records and see what they have in common

Comment: @KeithL except as it stands they can't produce both results in the same environment :)

Comment: there are a few places to filter the data set (i'd look at filters first as you have less in the report). Any internal parameters that lead to filters?

Comment: @DaleBurrell... he says he gets 8070 in SSMS and the report spits out 8063. He can compare both data sets (I'd do it in SSMS) but he can do it in Excel by sorting and manually looking. But finding those 7 records will be the quickest way to find out how things are dropping out

Comment: I agree - finding the missing 7 records is the quickest way to solving the issue

Comment: Put a trace on the server when you execute the report. You'll see exactly what SSRS is sending to the server then copy/paste into SSMS and compare. As Dale Burrell said, it's most likely the date parameters or maybe report's datasource is pointing to another server instance?

Comment: So, a couple of responses to the comments, Both the report and the SQL query  are going against the same database on the same server 100% sure about that. The clm.DateReceived is a datetime, as are the parameters. There are no filters in the report (It returns more data than the query anyway. I'll try a trace when I get into the office tomorrow, and I'll try and find the missing records in Excel.

Comment: as @AlanSchofield suggests, a trace will help, in case the trace returns the same query do as keithl says. In SSRS, you can set filters on Dataset, tablix and group level. check all of these in case you've got a filter somewhere

Comment: From my understanding, you've entered the query in your dataset as a "Text" query type.  Have you tried adding the query as a StoredProcedure and simply getting the data imported in that way?  That would ensure the results are coming from the SQL execution and would take minimal effort to adapt your report.